# Why does modulo division go wrong for mix of size_t and unsigned int in C++

Tags: c++, static-cast

Given a program

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     const size_t DoW = 7;
     const unsigned int DAYS_OF_WEEK = static_cast<unsigned int> (DoW);
     unsigned int dayOfFirstDay = 0;
     unsigned int _firstDayOfWeek = 1;
     unsigned int diff = (DAYS_OF_WEEK+ (dayOfFirstDay - _firstDayOfWeek) ) % DAYS_OF_WEEK;
     cout << "diff = ("  << DAYS_OF_WEEK << " + (" << dayOfFirstDay << " - " << _firstDayOfWeek << ")) %" << DAYS_OF_WEEK
         << " = " << diff << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

The output of that program is

```
diff = (7 + (0 - 1)) %7 = 6
```

which is expected. But a modified program without `static_cast`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     const size_t DAYS_OF_WEEK = 7;
     unsigned int dayOfFirstDay = 0;
     unsigned int _firstDayOfWeek = 1;
     unsigned int diff = (DAYS_OF_WEEK+ (dayOfFirstDay - _firstDayOfWeek) ) % DAYS_OF_WEEK;
     cout << "diff = ("  << DAYS_OF_WEEK << " + (" << dayOfFirstDay << " - " << _firstDayOfWeek << ")) %" << DAYS_OF_WEEK
         << " = " << diff << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
diff = (7 + (0 - 1)) %7 = 3
```

which is not expected. Why?

(Both programs are compiled with `g++` 9.3.0 on Ubuntu 64 Bit)

Comment: `DAYS_OF_WEEK` has a different type, so the wraparounds result in different numbers, print `DAYS_OF_WEEK+ (dayOfFirstDay - _firstDayOfWeek)` in both versions.

Comment: The maximum number that an `unsigned int` can have is `4,294,967,295` so if you use `unsigned int` as your data type, `0-1` evaluates to that. And `( 7 + ( 4294967295 ) ) % 7 == 3`.

Comment: @alle_meije -- the range of values that an integer type can represent depends on the compiler. The C and C++ standards require only that `unsigned int` is large enough to represent values from 0 through 65,535, i.e., 16 bits. Many compilers these days support a larger range, and 4,294,967,295 is the upper limit for a 32-bit unsigned integer. The upper limit is much larger than that for a 64-bit unsigned integer. Your analysis is correct for 32-bit integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems on your platform `size_t` is 64-bit, and `unsigned int` is 32-bit.

There is no [integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) to 64-bits<sup>1</sup>. This is the danger of mixing 64-bit operands in expressions.

So a 32-bit wraparound of -1 remains as 4294967295 when converted to 64 bits.

And we get 7 + 4294967295 (performed in 64 bits) = 4294967302 (no wraparound).

4294967302 % 7 = 3

---

<sup>1</sup> Except for systems where (`unsigned`) `int` itself is 64 bits, which is currently unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Such result can happen when `size_t` has more width than `unsigned int`.

The subtraction of `unsigned int` and `unsigned int` wraps around and results in `unsigned int`. `0 - 1`  results in `-1`, and it may become `0xffffffff` when `unsigned int` is 4-byte long.

Then, adding that with another `unsigned int` will result in `unsigned int`, so the result looks like normal subtraction and addition.

On the other hand, adding with `size_t` will have it calculate in `size_t` domain, so truncation doesn't happen and the value `7 + 0xffffffff` will be divided instead of `7 - 1`.

Here is an example code to check the values before division:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>

int main()
{
     const size_t DoW = 7;
     const unsigned int DAYS_OF_WEEK = static_cast<unsigned int> (DoW);
     unsigned int dayOfFirstDay = 0;
     unsigned int _firstDayOfWeek = 1;
     size_t to_add = dayOfFirstDay - _firstDayOfWeek;
     size_t diff_uint = DAYS_OF_WEEK+ (dayOfFirstDay - _firstDayOfWeek);
     size_t diff_sizet = DoW+ (dayOfFirstDay - _firstDayOfWeek);
     std::cout << "sizeof(unsigned int) = " << sizeof(unsigned int) << '\n';
     std::cout << "sizeof(size_t) = " << sizeof(size_t) << '\n';
     std::cout << std::hex;
     std::cout << "to add     : 0x" << to_add << '\n';
     std::cout << "diff_uint  : 0x" << diff_uint << '\n';
     std::cout << "diff_sizet : 0x" << diff_sizet << '\n';
     return 0;
}
```

Here is [an example of output](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cJh3zEtjNl9Y5RNi):

```
sizeof(unsigned int) = 4
sizeof(size_t) = 8
to add     : 0xffffffff
diff_uint  : 0x6
diff_sizet : 0x100000006
```

Answer (score 1):

`dayOfFirstDay - _firstDayOfWeek` is an `unsigned int`. As `_firstDayOfWeek` is greater than `dayOfFirstDay` the value is an underflow and wrap around and becomes max value of `unsigned int`. Let's call this value `max_uint`.

On the other hand `DAYS_OF_WEEK` is a `size_t` which is probably a wider type than `unsigned int`. This means that `DAYS_OF_WEEK + max_uint` is not overflowing. So you end-up computing `max_uint % 7`. But `max_uint % 7` is *not* equal to `-1` ...

Answer (score 0):

Try it with less obfuscation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main() {
  printf("0u - 1u = %u\n", 0u - 1u);
  printf("7u + (0u - 1u) = %u\n", 7u + (0u - 1u));
  printf("7zu + (0u - 1u) = %zu\n", size_t{7} + (0u - 1u));
}
```

The output I get:

```
0u - 1u = 4294967295
7u + (0u - 1u) = 6
7zu + (0u - 1u) = 4294967302
```

As you can see, `0u - 1u` results in a wraparound. Adding this huge number to an `unsigned int` results in another wraparound. Adding it to a `size_t` doesn't as the entire value is representable. For that reason, you get different results after the modulus operator.

Answer (score 0):

In the initializer expression of this declaration

```
unsigned int diff = (DAYS_OF_WEEK+ (dayOfFirstDay - _firstDayOfWeek) ) % DAYS_OF_WEEK;
```

the sub-expression `(dayOfFirstDay - _firstDayOfWeek)` is equal to the maximum value of the type `unsigned int`.

Thus in this sub-expression  when `DAYS_OF_WEEK` has the type `unsigned int`

```
(DAYS_OF_WEEK+ (dayOfFirstDay - _firstDayOfWeek) )
```

an overflow occurs.

When `DAYS_OF_WEEK` has the type `size_t` when neither overflow occurs.

This is the reason of different results.